# Filter a complex object with Linq

Tags: c#, linq, nested-generics

I need to filter a IEnumerable list based on this complex object. I need to perform a comparison operator on one of the nested dictionary elements. Right now I have a where clause on the parent object. How can I construct linq extension methods to filter on one of the key elements in the inner most dictionary?

```
/* Object */
public class AuditData
{
    public string Agent { get; set; }
    public AuditDataAction Action { get; set; }
}
/* Inner Object */
public class AuditDataAction
{
    public AuditDataAction()
    {
        Data = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>();
    }
    public IList<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>> Data { get; set; }
}

/* Code */
var myData =
    auditRepository.GetAuditEntriesFor(new AuditData {Rim = rimNo})
        .Where(d => d.Action.Adjent == "111").ToList();
```

Comment: Why are you creating a new `AuditData` and how would you expect to be able to call `Where` on it? And what sort of filter are you trying to perform? (I have to say, that list of dictionaries with dictionaries as values fills me with horror. You may well want to consider an intermediate named collection type to make it clearer.)

Comment: Yes, I have to agree. This is not code I created but need to add functionality to. I'm hoping to use it and not refactor all of the existing code base.  The .where works because the returned is IEnumerable<AuditData>.

Comment: The "new AuditData" is ultimately used to inject parameters into a SP.

Comment: Ah, I had missed the `)` at the end of `new AuditData { ...}`. It makes more sense now. It's still not clear what you're trying to query though.

Comment: To pair down the items in IEnumerable<AuditData>, I need to look at data inside the one of the dictionaries and see if a key exists or not to make this decision. 
Here is a declaration that illustrates of what the data structure looks like.  
I wish to keep the list element if the KeyOfInterest exists.

Comment: /* declaration */
<code>
    auditData.Action.Data = new List<Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>>
    {
        new Dictionary<string, Dictionary<string, object>>
        {
            {
                "KeyOfInterest", new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                    {"Key1", value1},
                    {"Key2", value2}
                }
            }
        }
    };

Comment: Please edit your *question* to show what's required. You have much more freedom to format it clearly that way, and anyone reading the question won't have to look through all the comments.